# How to use data which belongs to factor data type as argument in function in r

Tags: r, function, debugging, arguments

> My data is in this format,especially sex and ethnic are factors.

```
>head(scr)
  age scr    sex ethnic
1  48 1.2 Female  Other
2   7 0.8   Male  Black
3  62 1.8 Female   <NA>
4  48 3.8 Female  Other
5  51 1.4   Male  Other
```

> The function is mainly to calculate the equation:
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPdNj.png)
>   But it shows the sex and ethnic arguments are missing with no default when I enter the data.

```
egfr.mdrd4(scr[1,])
```

So, how to change the function or data type of sex and ethnic to run this function?

```
egfr.mdrd4 <- function(scr, age, sex, ethnic){
  if (sex == "Female")
    n<-0.742
  else
    n<-1
  if (ethnic == "Black")
    m<-1.212
  else
    m<-1
  mdrd<-175*scr^(-1.154)*age^(-0.203)*n*m
return (mdrd) 
}
egfr.md(scr[1,])
```

Comment: Try `if (as.character(sex) == "Female")` and the same with `ethnic`.

Comment: You could also convert `sex` and `ethnic` to character: e.g.: `scr$sex <- as.character(scr$sex)`

Comment: Thanks for your help,but I already tried this method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- `egfr.mdrd4` takes 4 arguments but the code shown in the question is passing it one argument
- the columns in the `scr` data frame are not in the same order as the arguments to `egfr.mdrd4`
- if there are NA values in the factor columns that are not levels then the code is trying to compare NA
- the code is not vectorized (this may or may not be a problem for you)

Try this.  The code has been revised to pass a single argument `scr` rather than 4 arguments.

Also we compare `addNA(sex)` to `"Female"` and `addNA(ethnic)` to `"Black"` which will cause any NA to be added as a factor level so that comparing NA to the indicated character strings results in the false leg being taken.  (An alternative to using `addNA` would be to use conditions such as `!is.na(sex) && sex == "Female"` which is also false for NA.  It uses the short-circuit && operator which only evaluates its right hand side if the left hand side is true.)

In addition, `if` has been vectorized using `ifelse`.

```
egfr.mdrd4v2 <- function(scr) with(scr, {
  n <- ifelse(addNA(sex) == "Female", 0.742, 1)
  m <- ifelse(addNA(ethnic) == "Black", 1.212, 1)
  mdrd <- 175*scr^(-1.154)*age^(-0.203)*n*m
  mdrd
})
egfr.mdrd4v2(scr)
## [1]  47.94848 184.85020  28.51031  12.67885  53.42808
```

### Note

The input `scr` in reproducible form is

```
scr <- structure(list(age = c(48L, 7L, 62L, 48L, 51L), scr = c(1.2, 
0.8, 1.8, 3.8, 1.4), sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), ethnic = structure(c(2L, 1L, NA, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Black", "Other"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", 
"scr", "sex", "ethnic"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), class = "data.frame")
```

### Update

Revised based on comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if the ethnic label is "<NA>", the result of the function will be <"NA">, how to change it to make the result into numeric?

Comment: Have revised my assumed input and modified the answer accordingly.